# What is the Date Format for "Fri Jun 05 00:00:00 PDT 2015"

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to determine what java date format string to use for

```
"Fri Jun 05 00:00:00 PDT 2015"
```

Right now I am using

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

But this yields

```
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jun 05 00:00:00 PDT 2015" 
  (through reference chain:....
```

Comment: `MM` should be `MMM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need one additional `M` for the month:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy
```

This is mentioned in [the Javadocs of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **Month:** If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Comment: Note that it's good to specify the `Locale` parameter as well if you expect the dates in English: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);` Otherwise it may fail in some other country.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, I missed that one in the docs, and for the Locale note, this is pretty complete now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

### `Locale` is as important as the pattern

Irrespective of the applicable pattern, it's important to use `Locale` as a date-time parsing/formatting type (e.g. the smart and vivid `DateTimeFormatter` of the modern API, or the notorious and error-prone `SimpleDateFormat` of the legacy API) is `Locale`-sensitive. Since your date-time string is in English, you should use `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

For the abbreviated month name, you need to use `MMM` instead of `MM`.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:m:s zzz u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Fri Jun 05 00:00:00 PDT 2015", dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-06-05T00:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

For whatsoever reason, if you need an instance of `java.util.Date` from this object of `ZonedDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** Ask your publisher to send the timezone name in the format, [Region/City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as shown in the above output. The three-letter timezone name (e.g. PDT) is ambiguous and hence, error-prone.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>